# SQLite - select expression is very slow

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm experiencing some heavy performance-issues with a query in SQLite. Currently there are around 20000 entries in the table **activity_tbl** and about 40 in the table **activity_data_tbl**. I have an index for both of the columns used in the query below, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the performance at all.

```
SELECT a._id, a.start_time + b.length AS time 
FROM activity_tbl a INNER JOIN activity_data_tbl b 
       ON a.activity_data_id = b._data_id 
WHERE time > ? 
ORDER BY 2 
LIMIT 1
```

As you can see, I select one column and a value created from adding two columns together. I guess this is what's causing the low performance, since the query is very fast if I just select a.start_time or b.length.

Do you guys have any suggestion for how I could optimize this?

Comment: Can you post the schema with indices (`.s`)?

Comment: Two comments: Don't mark the questions answered by changing the title, instead put a check mark next to one of the answers below (if the answer is your own, you can reply to your own question and mark that answer correct).  Also, filtering for a small start time may not (depending on the "shape" of your data) give you identical results to your original query.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an index on the time column. This should speed up the query

Answer (score 0):

This query is not optimizable using indexes for the filter part since you are filtering and ordering on a calculated value.  To optimize the query you will either need to filter on one of the actual table columns (starttime or length) or pre-compute the time values before querying.

The only place an index will help, and I assume you have one, is on b.data_id.

Answer (score 0):

A compound index may help. According to its docs, SQLite tries to avoid to access the table, if the index has enough information. So if the engine did its homework it will recognize that the index is enough to compute the where clause value and spare some time. If it does not work, only the pre-computation will do.

If you are more often confronted with similar tasks, please read this: http://www.sqlite.org/rtree.html