# SQLite read time per row increases with total number of rows: workaround? (Python 2.7, OSX)

Tags: python, macos, sqlite

I have an SQLite database containing several tables, two of which have over a million rows. I'm using Python 2.7 on OSX and the SQLite3 module.

I tried to read all the data from the tables into memory with a `SELECT` statement (without `WHERE` or anything of that nature) using the cursor's `execute()` method, followed by its `fetchall()` method. An hour later I decided to interrupt the process because I couldn't tell whether it had crashed. So I tried again using the cursor as an iterator and telling it to print the number of seconds elapsed every 10000 rows retrieved.

I found that while this method could retrieve the whole of a 150000 row table in about 6 seconds, with a 2500000 row table, it takes about 40 seconds per 10000 rows to begin with (60 seconds for some of the earliest batches), accelerating to about 20 seconds per 10000 rows from the millionth row onwards. So my question is: why is this happening, and what's a good solution to or workaround for it? An obvious workaround would be to break up large tables into smaller ones (or to give up on SQLite entirely and use something else) but that's not really very elegant.

Many other questions on Stack Overflow relate to slow read performance with relatively complex queries in SQLite (e.g. [SQLite - select expression is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014262/sqlite-select-expression-is-very-slow)). But this question relates to the simplest possible kind of query, e.g. `SELECT a,b,c,d FROM x`.

I've given the OS, programming language, and wrapper that I'm using above, but I'm not sure how relevant they are to the problem. For example, if I try to inspect these large tables using the Firefox extension, SQLite Manager, Firefox just seems to hang. I've also tried switching to the apsw wrapper (https://github.com/rogerbinns/apsw) but there was no improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to read all the data from the tables into memory…

Don't do that.

Even if mediated by a cursor.

There are few cases where you actually need the entire database with an in-core representation and your's is probably not one of them.

Dragging all that data into memory is expensive as your tests have shown you. The cost of doing a fetchall is one of the major issues that DMBs were designed to cope with. For any database where you could build a system that's "good enough" for today. It will grow to exceed core tomorrow.

**added in reply to comment**:

It appears that [PyTables is a commonly used tool](http://www.pytables.org/moin) to handle memory busting data. I have no experience with [PyTables](http://www.pytables.org/moin).

Comment: You're right that reading a whole table into memory would usually be counterproductive (why bother with a database???). But the thing is that I sometimes have to do calculations that require the whole dataset to be represented in a matrix, and then THIS happens. Is there any way of reducing the cost of a fetchall?

Comment: @Westcroft_to_Apse Thanks for understanding the DB-dup-to-core principle; it is refresshing to see someone know that in advance. Please see "added" for a more complete answer.

Comment: Thanks very much, @msw - it looks as if PyTables was created for precisely this sort of use, so I'm going to try it out before accepting your answer.

Comment: Once I've got enough rep to be able to edit questions, I'll edit mine so that it's clearer why yours was the right answer to it, @msw...